# Action not getting invoked mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I am developing an application in asp.net using mvc4. I am very new to asp.net. Following is my global.asax code

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapHttpRoute(

name: "DefaultApi",

routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",

defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

);

routes.MapRoute(

name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",

defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", 

id =   UrlParameter.Optional }

);



}
```

Also

```
protected void Application_Start()

{
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

}
```

Also I am having a controller named `Default1Controller`, which has a action method named MyAction. On the click of `button` I want this Method to get executed. But while debugging the control does not come here i.e the method does not gets invoked. Following is my controller code

```
public class Default1Controller : Controller

{
    //
    // GET: /Default1/

public ActionResult Default1()
{

return View();

}

public ActionResult MyAction()
{
return View();
}


}
```

Also following is the cshtml
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Default1";

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Default1</h2>

<div>

<p>Welcome to the world of MVC!!!!</p>

<div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me"

onclick="window.location.href('@Url.Action("MyAction","Default1Controller")')" />

</div>



</div>
```

On clicking on the button, this is the error that i get

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: `/Default1Controller/MyAction`

---

Can anyone tell me where 
I am going wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated. Also I would like to add that I am using VS 2010. .Net 4.0.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="window.location.href('@Url.Action("MyAction","Default1")')" />
```

Comment: Would you please accept it as answer if it has resolved your query?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include 'Controller' as part of the controller name when using `Url.Action()`, this applies anywhere where you pass in the controller name as a string:

Also, window.location.href is not a function so should be set using =.

This should load to the correct action:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Action("MyAction","Default1")'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href is a property instead of a method, so you should change the code like this :

```
onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Default1/MyAction")';"
```